# Why does the AdminClient not throw an exception?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka AdminClient, that when Kafkaserver is active, then it will return true otherwise false.

```
  private def health(server: String): Boolean = {
    val props = new Properties
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server)
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG, "10000")
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "5000")

    try {
      AdminClient
        .create(props)
        .listTopics()
        .names()
        .get()
      true
    } catch {
      case _: InterruptedException => false
      case _: ExecutionException => false
    }
```

Now, I have a scenario that Kafka is offline und the method returns neither `false` or `true`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Applying the comment, I cannot seem to replicate the issue, for example, the following

```
  val kafkaFuture = new KafkaFutureImpl
  kafkaFuture.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("splosh"))
  println(
    try {
      kafkaFuture.get()
    } catch {
      case _: InterruptedException => "boom"
      case _: ExecutionException => "crash"
    }
  )
```

outputs `crash`, which shows `case _: ExecutionException` branch was hit correctly.

Comment: The method `names()` return a Future but `get()` waits until the result is ready.

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html

Comment: The method `get` does not return a future, it returns a result. Here is the description of get method `Waits if necessary for this future to complete, and then returns its result.` I do not get, what are you trying to say.

Comment: `kafkaFuture.get()` should simulate what happens with `....names().get()` because `names()` returns `KafkaFuture`. So what I am saying is if an exception is thrown at the point of calling `get` then `try-catch` should work fine as it would be an `ExecutionException`. Are you sure `AdminClient` is throwing an exception at all?

Comment: But why I did not get a result, when calling get or an exception.

Comment: By not getting a result, do you mean when calling `health` method it never returns as in it blocks forever?

Comment: By calling health it does not throw an exception at all. In the debug modus, it does not  stop at exception statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.util.Try

private def health(server: String): Boolean = {
  val props = new Properties
  props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server)
  props.put(AdminClientConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG, "10000")
  props.put(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "5000")

  Try (
    AdminClient
      .create(props)
      .listTopics()
      .names()
      .get()
  ).isSuccess
}
```

The reason for that happen is that another exception is getting throwed.